# How do you make a sound stop playing when you leave a view controller and go to another one?

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I'm creating an application which plays a sound a`enter code here`t the start of the application being launched. I would like the sound to stop when the next view controller is pulled up but it won't. Thanks!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Waltz" ofType:@"wav"];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error: NULL];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: what do you mean when the next view controller is pulled up?

Comment: When you move to other view controller from your root view controller does it play sound?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a way to access the same instance of AVAudioPlayer (eg. a Helper/Manager class, or more messily store it as a property in AppDelegate and then access that from your view controller)

Then from your view controller's viewDidAppear (or wherever it suits you) call `[audioPlayer stop];`